# Where is the php.ini file in Ubuntu hardy?

Tags: php5

Where is the php.ini file in Ubuntu hardy?

The file found in path called /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.ucf-dist.

Do I need to rename file 'php.ini.ucf-dist' to 'php.ini'?

Where is the system currently reading the php information when I run info.php file?

I tried to compare one item what gets displayed when I run info.php file and when I edit the 'php.ini.ucf-dist' file. The 'memory_limit' shows 128M when I run info.php file but in the 'php.ini.ucf-dist' file it is set to 16M. So this cant be the same file being read by the system currently?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `phpinfo();` will tell you which php.ini file is loaded. For example, mine says:

> Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: This is the preferred way since it tells you which php.ini your system is actually using.  The `locate` or `whereis` command is also your friend in situations like this...

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming file to:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

If your info.php is working you can search for 'Loaded Configuration File' and there will be path to file from which php module is reading options.